# Unable Create trigger on mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I use XAMMP with phpmyadmin 3.2.4 - mySQL 5.1.41.

I've created a table in mySQL and I want to create a trigger on tbl_users, but mySQL shows this error:

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON TBL_USERS FOR INSERT AS IF(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TBL_USERS WHERE USERNAME IN' at line 1

```
CREATE TABLE TBL_USERS
(
ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
USERNAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
PASSWORD VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
EMAIL VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
STATUS INT DEFAULT 1,
TYPE_USER INT DEFAULT 1,
DISPLAY_NAME VARCHAR(50) NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_USERS PRIMARY KEY (ID),
CONSTRAINT UN_USERNAME UNIQUE(USERNAME)
)
```

Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER CHECK_USERNAME ON TBL_USERS FOR INSERT
AS
IF(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TBL_USERS WHERE USERNAME IN (SELECT USERNAME FROM inserted))>1
BEGIN
PRINT 'THIS USERNAME IS EXISTS'
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Trigger activation time can be BEFORE or AFTER. You must specify the activation time when you define a trigger. You use BEFORE keyword if you want to process action prior to the change is made on the table and AFTER if you need to process action after change are made.
```

**Try like this :**

```
create trigger userIns BEFORE INSERT ON table_name
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
...
END
```

Comment: I used this trigger in sql server 2008 and it run successful.